# How does patterns help loose coupling?

Tags: design-patterns, instantiation, loose-coupling, responsibility, code-complexity

I'm new to java patterns and I'm trying to figure out how it fits in to the REAL WORLD.
Most sites and books on patterns seems to be written by non-programmers.

**I'm trying to define how patterns help with coupling, and this is my definition so far. What I would like to know is what patterns are really useful for loose coupling, and are they worth the effort. Also, is my definition/understanding correct so far:**

"Coupling is the degree, two or more different objects, accesses and/or interacts with each other."

Tight coupling between two objects:

- Referencing/Instantiation : Many reverence to the other object, in
  many places,  in one or both objects (many to many references)
- Complexity : Usually many parameters required accessing functions, or
  the sequence of accessing different functions. No common interface
  for related objects.
- Responsibility : Doing work that should rather be done in the object
  being accessed, or another object. Accessing nested functions
  directly.
- Performance : Biggest reason why tight coupling is sometimes
  required, but should be minimized.

Loose coupling between two objects:

- Referencing/Instantiation : Few, but at least one reference in one
  object but not in both (one to few references)
  Patterns that help : Factory, Singleton, Builder, Composite
- Complexity : Few, well defined parameters (usually defined by an
  interface), with least possible sequence of functions (exp. open,
  fetch, close)
  Patterns that help : Adaptor, Bridge, Decorator, Facade, Command
- Responsibility : Only do work the object is responsible for doing and
  try to only access functions one level down.
  Patterns that help : Decorator, Chain of Responsibility, MVC
- Performance : Identify where performance needs to be, and keep those
  classes together - maybe even as nested classes, per definition
  tightly coupled.

Comment: See some of the other posts on the topic (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/02/LooseCouplingandtheBigPicture/)

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that is considered the best for loose coupling is IoC: Inversion of Control, made using the  Dependency Injection.

Basically if a class Alfa needs another object of class Beta, you have to instanciate manually Beta and pass it to Alfa (injection):

```
Beta myDependencyObject ....;
Alfa myObjectWithDependency(myDependencyObject);
```

In this way you expose the dependecy that Alfa has with Beta.